# Error file.exists(src) is not TRUE when installing R package from Git

Tags: r, git, package

I created an R package and pushed it to a git repository according to the following description:
https://pjnewcombe.wordpress.com/2014/05/31/using-rstudio-to-create-and-maintain-an-r-package-on-github/

The Git repository with the R package looks as follows:

[image: Git repository]

Now I am having difficulties installing the R package.
I tried the following:

```
library("remotes")
remotes::install_git("https://tfs.mygitserver.com/_git/packagename")
```

But I get the following error:

```
Downloading git repo https://tfs.mygitserver.com/_git/packagename
'/usr/bin/git' clone --depth 1 --no-hardlinks https://tfs.mygitserver.com/_git/packagename /tmp/RtmpCeNkBW/file649463b0480f7
Cloning into '/tmp/RtmpCeNkBW/file649463b0480f7'...
Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from Git:
  file.exists(src) is not TRUE
```

I was unable to find on Google what is the cause of this error.
How could I solve this issue?

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: The url in `remotes::install_git(url)` must point to a Git repo, so in particular it must end with `.git`.

Comment: It's useful that the console includes the `git` command. Have you tried running the `git clone` manually and looking at the results in the temp directory?

Comment: When I run `git clone https://tfs.mygitserver.com/_git/packagename` in the console, then a folder with name 'packagename' is created and it contains the same files as shown in the repository screenshot above.

Comment: I updated the screenshot of the git repository in the question above, such that it's more clear which files the git repository contains.